# C# OpenTK "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop.GameWindowSettings'"

Tags: c#, .net, opentk

I'm trying to a game with .NET Core, OpenTK, and VS19. Whenever i go to make a window, i get two errors.

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop.GameWindowSettings'
```

and

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop.NativeWindowSettings'
```

I've tried using many tutorial videos, and i get the same error for each. Did a bit of googling, and got no results that helped.

Program.cs:

```
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
using System;

namespace GREYLANDS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GameWindow window = new GameWindow(800, 600);
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice? Don't hesitate to ask for more info.

Comment: I just got it off of NUGET. Every time I reference GameWindow, it defaults to the Desktop one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenTK: Why is GraphicsMode not available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64534969/opentk-why-is-graphicsmode-not-available)

Answer (score 0):

```
public GameWindow(GameWindowSettings gameWindowSettings, NativeWindowSettings nativeWindowSettings);
```

Because of GameWindow don't from using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop; doesn't get int value in constructor.
Please check class NativeWindowSettings  and GameWindowSettings. There are some stuff to manipulate window.
You can do eg.

```
GameWindowSettings setting = new GameWindowSettings();
NativeWindowSettings nativeSettings = new NativeWindowSettings();
nativeSettings.Size = new OpenTK.Mathematics.Vector2i(800, 600);
GameWindow window = new GameWindow(setting, nativeSettings);
```