# OpenTK: Why is GraphicsMode not available?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I just started to learn OpenTK and stumbled upon a problem when going through [this tutorial](https://opentk.net/learn/chapter1/1-creating-a-window.html).

This is what I tried:

```
using System;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
using OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework;
namespace Testing
{
    public class GraphicsWindow : GameWindow
    {
        public GraphicsWindow(int width, int height, string title) : base(width, height, GraphicsMode.Default, title)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

The Enum GraphicsMode is not found for some reason (should be found in namespace OpenTK.Graphics). Another one is that GameWindow does not have a constructor taking 4 arguments.

I have installed the latest version of the OpenTK Nuget package (4.0.6). The project I created targets .NET Core.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

The tutorial is based on OpenTK 3.x, which was written for .NET framwork. OpenTK 4.x is written for .NET core. In 3.x the  `GameWindow` was part of the `OpenTK.Graphics` namespace. Now the class is contained in `OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop` and behaves different. The constructor has 2 arguments, `GameWindowSettings` and `NativeWindowSettings`.

```
namespace Testing
{
    public class GraphicsWindow : GameWindow
    {
        public GraphicsWindow(int width, int height, string title)
            : base(
                  new GameWindowSettings(),
                  new NativeWindowSettings()
                  {
                      Size = new OpenTK.Mathematics.Vector2i(width, height),
                      Title = title
                  })
            { }
    }
}
```

Alternatively create a static factory method:

```
namespace Testing
{
    public class GraphicsWindow : GameWindow
    {
        public static GraphicsWindow New(int width, int height, string title)
        {
            GameWindowSettings setting = new GameWindowSettings();
            NativeWindowSettings nativeSettings = new NativeWindowSettings();
            nativeSettings.Size = new OpenTK.Mathematics.Vector2i(width, height);
            nativeSettings.Title = title;
            return new GraphicsWindow(setting, nativeSettings);
        }

        public GraphicsWindow(GameWindowSettings setting, NativeWindowSettings nativeSettings) 
            : base(setting, nativeSettings)
        {}
    }
}
```

```cs
var myGraphicsWindow = GraphicsWindow.New(800, 600);
```

---

See also [OpenTK_hello_triangle](https://github.com/Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl/tree/master/OpenTK_hello_triangle)

Comment: Any Tutorial for OpenTK 4.x

Comment: @Justiciar I've some examples in a GitHub repository [Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl](https://github.com/Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl)