# Im getting an error when using the openTk GameWindow extention

Tags: c#, syntax-error, opentk

I started c# a few days ago and tried to use the openTk libary.

I installed it via commandline (using vsCode: dotnet add package OpenTK --version 4.2.0) and it seemed like it worked.
But in the internet, when searching for examples, they always use the Game :: GameWindow class.
When I type that, im getting an error.
Can you help me?
Heres my code:

```
using System;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;

namespace tk_test1
{
    public class Game : GameWindow
    {

    }
}
```

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSIpF.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenTK: Why is GraphicsMode not available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64534969/opentk-why-is-graphicsmode-not-available)

Comment: Read the error, it's telling you that you need to implement a constructor to call `GameWindow`'s constructor, since it doesn't have a default one.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're probably using OpenTK v4, So please check your version. In that case, your 'using' must looks like this:

```
using OpenTK.Windowing.Common;
using OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
```

Then, your GameWindow extends must works.

The Opentk.net shows only the docs for v3, these are samples of v4:
https://github.com/opentk/LearnOpenTK

Sample code

[image: 1]